# Question about Amit Agarwal's File Upload Forms

Tags: focus, addeventlistener

I am using [Amit Agarwal's File Upload Forms](https://digitalinspiration.com/product/file-upload-forms) add-on.  I am trying to figure out a way to add a button that skips to a specific input ("ctrlq-file-49" according to inspect).  I've used the rich HTML field to add a button with a specific id (skip-to-upload).  I then tried to add javascript in the "Advanced Settings" section of the sidebar, but I can't get anything to work.

This is what I tried:

```
var btn = document.getElementById("skip-to-upload");

btn.addEventListener('click', function (e){
document.getElementById("ctrlq-file-49").focus();
}, false);
```

Does anyone know a way to do this?

Comment: I added an event listener to the whole of the document that focuses on the input field I want on click, and it worked fine, but it doesn't seem to work from a button

Comment: EDIT: It doesn't seem to work on ANY element other than the entire document.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by adding jQuery.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#skip-arrow").click(function(){
    $("#ctrlq-file-49").focus();
  });
});
</script>
```